# Puerto de mysql en xampp mac

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, macos

quisiera saber como puedo ver en qué puerto está funcionando MySql.
Estoy usando Mac y XAMPP.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Suele ser el puerto `3306` o `3307`. En el mismo xampp o en el Monitor de Actividades podrás verlo. Hay muchos otros modos, quizá [el más simple es este](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864914/5587982) desde la Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías saberlo de 2 formas:

**1. Desde MySQL**

Ejecutando la siguiente consulta:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
```

**2. Usando Netstat**

Para ello deberías ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
netstat -tlnp
```

Con esto obtendrás un listado de los servicios activos y en que puerto están funcionando.

Lo más habitual es que sea el puerto `3306` o `3307`.

Comment: Hola. No tengo instalado MySql en mi Mac. Lo estoy usando a través de XAMPP. Deberia instalarlo globalmente?

Comment: Hola!, No creo que sea necesario. Desde XAMPP funciona muy bien. Te recomiendo que aprendas a usar Netstat, porque te va a valer cuando te ocurra este mismo problema con cualquier otra aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Podes verlo desde la aplicación de `XAMPP` así:

### Opción 1:

- Abrir `XAMPP`
- Solapa `Manage Servers`
- Seleccionar `MySQL Database`
- Presionar el botón `Configure`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Opción 2:

- Abrir `XAMPP`
- Solapa `Manage Servers`
- Seleccionar `MySQL Database`

  - Validar que este corriendo (*que este en verde*)
  - Si no esta corriendo, presionar el botón `Start`
- Ir a la solapa `Server Events`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, mi version de XAMPP no tiene la opción 'configure' en la ventana de Services. Tampoco tengo la ventana de Manage Services. Que version estas usando?

Comment: @Daro, en versiones anteriores lo podes encontrar en la solapa `Network`